# Why is windows so slow in opening files first time and is there a faster way

Tags: c++, windows, performance, file-io

This is Windows 7, 64 bit, Professional using

Consider a very simple loop

```
for (i = 0; i < names->size(); i++)
{
    std::string Name = names->at(i);
    HANDLE fileHandle = CreateFile(Name.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

    if (fileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        throw "Failed";
    }

    CloseHandle(fileHandle);
}
```

If I run this on a directory with 863 files, it takes slightly over 22 SECONDS, or 25 milliseconds/file.  The next time 169 milliseconds or 0.19 milliseconds/file.  If I just use find_file time on a fresh directory is very fast, about the 0.2 ms/file.  Although I used CreateFile here, other methods yield the same results.

Of course the answer is file caching: windows must be caching the information about file open.  Moreover, it must be disk access as if the directory is on an SSD, the first and second opens are about the same.

Now the seek time on these hard drives are only 9 ms, so does anyone know WHAT IS WINDOWS doing when it takes 25 milliseconds to open/close a file for only reading with NO reading.  But more importantly, is it possible to speed this up.  You might say 25 ms is fast, but I am playing video files so I need to read at about 33 ms and an actual read of data is in the 30 ms range, so the cost of opening is too high.

Any suggestions on how to open a ****load of files quickly would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the "so the cost of opening is too high" part. You can leave the file open. Why close it if you nead to read it again?

Comment: What are the times on the SSD?  You say the two are the same, but what are they?

Comment: You already know it has nothing to do with Windows, it only needs 0.19 msec.  Of course it is the *disk drive* that adds the time.  Seeking is very expensive, mechanical motion is slow, and everybody lies about their drive's worst statistic.  And it isn't just seek time, just waiting for the platter to rotate to the right spot already blows more than 4 msec.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I did not make myself clear.  Reopening is fast, it is the initial open that is slow. It is the initial open that is killing me.  As far as it has nothing to do with windows, I don't agree, it is like saying the driver of the car had nothing to do with the accident, it was the car.  Windows drives the drive.

Comment: When I see the CreateFile() and the CloseHandle() separate instead in a constructor and a destructor I'm getting nervous. This is 2014!

Comment: Why are you opening the file if you do not intend to read it?

Comment: The answer to my question below is the problem going on here too. You had Microsoft's built in security scans turned on. This causes CreateFile to slow down significantly and when you're reading a large number of files the time to read adds up. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870498/windows-createfile-slow-when-opening-a-large-number-of-files/45884512#45884512

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows does a *lot* under the hood when you open a file. I'm no expert, but I can mention filesystem maintenance (updating the access time, journaling, etc.) and access permission checks as two important items. Unfortunately I don't think you can make this any faster.

Of course if you don't plan to read anything from the file, and you're just checking if the file exists or reading some metadata like its modification time, there are faster ways to do that without opening the file.

Comment: Locking the file might add additional costs. So fiddling a little bit with opening and shared flags might be worth trying.

Comment: I think you are correct.  The initial OpenFile (CreateFile) serializes the access to the disk.  Thus if you have two opens in two threads, the latter waits for the former to finish, so multithreading is no solution.  But AFTER the initial open, the openfile does NOT lock the disk and files can be opened simultaneously in different threads.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this answer should be checked as accepted. The original question asks "why is it slow THE FIRST TIME it is open." The operating system has to do the same maintenance/journaling/checking/etc. on a file whether it is the first time or the twentieth time.

I am seeing the exact same thing under java. Run a program the first time that opens 4000 files one after another and the profiler shows that I am spending 96.4% of the program's time in sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.CreateFile0[native] (long, int, int, long, int, int).

Then if I run it again immediately it runs 20x times faster and the profiler shows I'm not even using CreateFile. In fact the JVM is selecting entirely different objects and methods to complete the Files.readAllLines invokation.

I suspect the OP is experience something similar and not the routine OS maintenance requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could do. One is, keep the files open after the initial file open if you know you are going to read them again soon.  Another is to cache their data in memory and only open them to save changes. This will only work if you aren't expecting the files to be changed by other programs.

If you are expecting them to be changed by other programs, you can still the second method of keeping their contents in memory, then regularly check the modification time. If it has changed, load them again.

The reason they load faster the second time is that their data is put in a cache, either by the hard drive itself or by the OS, or some combination of both, depending on your hardware and settings, so the second time you open them, it isn't being read from the drive, but from memory.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good chance that the slowness of accessing a file for the first time is due to on-demand anti-virus scanning.

Unless the file is in its exclusion list, Windows Defender will scan a file for viruses the first time it's opened. The factor will vary by file type and hardware etc, but in my scenario it's around 4 times faster for files in the exclusion list - I'm scanning ~11k files from cold in ~62 seconds with Defender, ~14 seconds without. ~5 seconds for subsequent hot scans in both scenarios.